# How to store the remaining bit of a file into a variable in c

Tags: c

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char line1[128];
  char line2[128];
  char line3[128];
  char rem_text[128];
  FILE *f;

  f = fopen((argv[1]), "r");
  if (!f) {
     printf("error");
  } else {
      fscanf(f, "%127[^\n]\n%127[^\n]\n%127[^\n]\n%127[^\n] ", line1, line2,line3, rem_text);
      printf("1:%s\n", line1);
      printf("2:%s\n", line2);
      printf("3:%s\n", line3);
      printf("4:%s\n", rem_text);
      fclose(f);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The Program works almost as expected, except for one detail.
What it is supposed to do is, take the first three lines of a file and store them in individual variables. (which works) but then I would like to store the entire remaining bit of the file into its own variable.
How do I do that?
Thanks in advance

If for example my `test.txt` file contains 
`Kapitel 1
chapter_21.txt
chapter_42.txt
'Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?'
'That depends a good deal on where you want to get to,' said the Cat.
'I don't much care where -' said Alice.
'Then it doesn't matter which way you go,' said the Cat.
'- so long as I get SOMEWHERE,' Alice added as an explanation.
'Oh, you're sure to do that,' said the Cat, 'if you only walk long enough.'`

I would like to store
`Kapitel 1` as Title

`chapter_21.txt` as chapter_a

`chapter_42.txt` as chapter_b

and

`'Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?'
'That depends a good deal on where you want to get to,' said the Cat.
'I don't much care where -' said Alice.
'Then it doesn't matter which way you go,' said the Cat.
'- so long as I get SOMEWHERE,' Alice added as an explanation.
'Oh, you're sure to do that,' said the Cat, 'if you only walk long enough.'` as rem_text

Comment: This will be much easier if you forget you ever heard of `fscanf` and use `fgets` instead.  (`getline` is even more convenient but not universally available.)

Comment: Do not use `scanf` to read lines but `fgets`: it is both simpler and more robust. What do you think could happen in the first line was 132 characters long?

Comment: Posting example data would add clarity.  If `f` contains a line longer than 127 or so characters, this code has UB.  Check `fscanf()` return results.

Comment: @chux I have added an example into the question

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47596339/2410359

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I store only the ending bit of a file in a variable in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47596339/how-would-i-store-only-the-ending-bit-of-a-file-in-a-variable-in-c)