# How would I store only the ending bit of a file in a variable in c

Tags: c

My Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char line1[128];
  char line2[128];
  char line3[128];
  char rem_text[128];
  FILE *f;

  f = fopen((argv[1]), "r");
  if (!f) {
     printf("error");
  } else {
      fscanf(f, "%127[^\n]\n%127[^\n]\n%127[^\n]\n%127[^\n] ", line1, line2,line3, rem_text);
      printf("1:%s\n", line1);
      printf("2:%s\n", line2);
      printf("3:%s\n", line3);
      printf("4:%s\n", rem_text);
      fclose(f);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The Program works almost as expected, except for one detail.
What it is supposed to do is, take the first three lines of a file and store them in individual variables. (which works) but then I would like to store the entire remaining bit of the file into its own variable.
How do I do that?

If for example my test.txt file contains

```
Kapitel 1
chapter_21.txt
chapter_42.txt
'Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?'
'That depends a good deal on where you want to get to,' said the Cat.
'I don't much care where -' said Alice.
'Then it doesn't matter which way you go,' said the Cat.
'- so long as I get SOMEWHERE,' Alice added as an explanation.
'Oh, you're sure to do that,' said the Cat, 'if you only walk long enough.'
```

I would like to store `Kapitel 1` as `Title`

`chapter_21.txt` as `chapter_a`

`chapter_42.txt` as `chapter_b`

and

```
'Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?'
'That depends a good deal on where you want to get to,' said the Cat.
'I don't much care where -' said Alice.
'Then it doesn't matter which way you go,' said the Cat.
'- so long as I get SOMEWHERE,' Alice added as an explanation.
'Oh, you're sure to do that,' said the Cat, 'if you only walk long enough.'
```

as `rem_text`

Comment: `printf("error\n")` is almost always wrong.  Errors belong on stderr, and you get more information with: `if(!f) { perror(argv[1]); ...`

Comment: Do you mean "remaining file" with "remaining bit"? `Bit` in this context can be a bit confusing.

Comment: `scanf` is the wrong tool.  Read the data into a buffer.  Find the first 3 newline characters and assign pointers to the first character of each line.  You'll need to dynamically size the buffer if you want to store the entire file in memory (unless you are content to only work with files up to a certain size).

Comment: There's also `fgets()` and `getline()` for reading full lines (the latter even does the memory allocation for you). But you'll need to decide how to store the longer part. Do you want it line-by-line with an array of pointers to the lines, or just one big string, or something else?

Comment: Could have saved yourself some typing & time - someone else asked the *exact* same question earlier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595456/how-to-store-the-remaining-bit-of-a-file-into-a-variable-in-c

Comment: Do you actually need storing first three lines into variables? You use them afterwards? Can you just skip first three lines, then print the `"Kapitel 1\nchapter_a\nchapter_b"` and the text's remainder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly because I don't get to write C much these days, and to provide some examples, and most importantly (although this isn't really the right forum) to solicit the extreme criticism likely to follow to sharpen my now dulled coding skills, I would propose:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *Fopen(const char *path, const char *mode) {
        FILE *rv = fopen(path, mode);
        if(rv == NULL) {
                perror(path);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        return rv;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        char buf[4096];
        char *line[4] = {0};
        FILE *f;

        f = argc > 1 ? Fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
        if(fread(buf, sizeof *buf, sizeof buf, f) == sizeof buf) {
                fprintf(stderr, "This file is too big.  Need to implement dynamic sizing\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        line[0] = buf;
        for(int i=1; line[i-1] && i < sizeof line / sizeof *line; i++) {
                line[i] = strchr(line[i-1], '\n');
                if(line[i]) {
                        *line[i] = '\0';
                        line[i] += 1;
                }
        }
        for(int i=0; i < sizeof line / sizeof *line; i++) {
                printf("line[%d] = %s\n", i, line[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Note that dynamically sizing the arrays is a good thing to know how to do.  Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, I ran the code, and got the following result: `line[0] = Kapitel 1
line[1] = chapter_21.txt
line[2] = chapter_42.txt
'Would you tell me, please, which way I ought to go from here?'
'That depends a good deal on where you want to get to,' said the Cat.
'I don't much care where -' said Alice.
'Then it doesn't matter which way you go,' said the Cat.
'- so long as I get SOMEWHERE,' Alice added as an explanation.
'Oh, you're sure to do that,' said the Cat, 'if you only walk long enough.'
?`

Comment: I had at one point hard-coded a 3 instead of a 4 in the loops.  Perhaps you were running that pre-edited code.

Comment: `strchr(line[i-1]...)` --> `line[i-1]` may lack null character termination leading to UB.

Comment: `printf("line[%d] = %s\n", i, line[i]);` may attempt `printf("line[%d] = %s\n", i, 0);`.  Welcome back to C.